# Parse error on facebook sdk?

Tags: facebook, parsing, sdk

This code:

```
    $clientid ='**************';
    $secret = '********************';


    //Include sdk classes
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );

    use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;



    // init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($clientid,$secret);

    // login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $redirect );

    try {
      $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
      // When Facebook returns an error
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
    }



    $me = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/me'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className);
    echo $me->getName();
```

throws the error:

[18-Nov-2014 12:57:31 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in ....... on line 53

line 53 being:

```
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className);
```

I copied and pasted that block of code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/4.0.0
so how can there be a parse error?

PHP version 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This version of the Facebook SDK for PHP requires PHP 5.4 or greater.

Source: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4